# drag and drop not working properly in the Edit flow

Tags: javascript, jointjs

No error in the console , Iam using the below Function for changing the position of shape in the paper if I change the position and release the mouse button It still in dragging  once click the shape then it will placed in the position

```
graph.on('change:position', function(cell) {
});
```

// click function

```
 paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
      if(aliasthis.selectedPipelineId!=""){
      cellView.options.interactive == false;
    }
    else{
      aliasthis.cellId = cellView.model.id;
      if( cellView.options.interactive == false)
        {
          console.log('----drag true---')
          cellView.options.interactive = true;
        } else if( cellView.options.interactive == true)
        {
          console.log('----drag false---')
          //aliasthis.cellId = '';
          cellView.options.interactive = false;
        }
        if( cellView.model.id )
        {

         // aliasthis.cellId = cellView.model.id;
          if( cellView.model.attributes.type == "connection")
            {
              aliasthis.connOpt = cellView.model.attributes.typeLabel
              aliasthis.pipeOpt = '';
            }
            else if( cellView.model.attributes.type == "dataaggregate")
            {
              aliasthis.pipeOpt = cellView.model.attributes.typeLabel;
              aliasthis.connOpt = '';
            }

            aliasthis.labelChange(cellView)

            aliasthis.graphdesign = aliasthis.connectFlowSchemaJson;
            console.log('----flowjson----');console.log( aliasthis.connectFlowSchemaJson )
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code sample?

Comment: okay i will provide  the code